# reload tableview view like refresh

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am populating tableview with json data and its work successfully but now I want to update tableview on refresh button click in refresh button i call again existing `func` which I create to call api let me show you my code

**Code**

```
func OverdueList(){
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!]
    print(params)
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.request(inspectionsList, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let data = json["inspections_overdue_data"]
            print(data)
            if data == []{
                self.viewNodata.isHidden = false
            }else{
                data.array?.forEach({ (iunOverDue) in
                    let iOveList = OvedueModel(surveyor_id: iunOverDue["surveyor_id"].stringValue, country: iunOverDue["country"].stringValue, time: iunOverDue["time"].stringValue, address2: iunOverDue["address2"].stringValue, address3: iunOverDue["address3"].stringValue, notes: iunOverDue["notes"].stringValue, house_num: iunOverDue["house_num"].stringValue, name: iunOverDue["name"].stringValue, address1: iunOverDue["address1"].stringValue, latitude: iunOverDue["latitude"].stringValue, eircode: iunOverDue["eircode"].stringValue, date_inspected: iunOverDue["date_inspected"].stringValue, property_id: iunOverDue["property_id"].stringValue, county: iunOverDue["county"].stringValue, client_id: iunOverDue["client_id"].stringValue, longitude: iunOverDue["longitude"].stringValue)
                    self.searchResult = self.overDueData
                    self.overDueData.append(iOveList)
                })

                self.tblOvedue.reloadData()
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
}
```

I am calling this func for populating table view and I am doing like below

```
@IBAction func btnRefreshTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      OverdueList()
    }
```

the issue was that after re calling this function data again and again repeated so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but: In Swift should types start with big capital letter, and variables/constant/methods with small: `OverdueLis()` -> `overdueList()`. Next, don't use snake_case in Swift, use camelCase: `u_ID` -> `uID`. And finally, try to avoid using *SwiftyJSON*, since you can use `Codable` which is recommended to decoding and encoding data.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code :

```
func OverdueList(){


    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!]
    print(params)
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.request(inspectionsList, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            self.overDueData.removeAll()
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let data = json["inspections_overdue_data"]
            print(data)
            if data == []{
                self.viewNodata.isHidden = false
            }else{
                data.array?.forEach({ (iunOverDue) in
                    let iOveList = OvedueModel(surveyor_id: iunOverDue["surveyor_id"].stringValue, country: iunOverDue["country"].stringValue, time: iunOverDue["time"].stringValue, address2: iunOverDue["address2"].stringValue, address3: iunOverDue["address3"].stringValue, notes: iunOverDue["notes"].stringValue, house_num: iunOverDue["house_num"].stringValue, name: iunOverDue["name"].stringValue, address1: iunOverDue["address1"].stringValue, latitude: iunOverDue["latitude"].stringValue, eircode: iunOverDue["eircode"].stringValue, date_inspected: iunOverDue["date_inspected"].stringValue, property_id: iunOverDue["property_id"].stringValue, county: iunOverDue["county"].stringValue, client_id: iunOverDue["client_id"].stringValue, longitude: iunOverDue["longitude"].stringValue)
                    self.searchResult = self.overDueData
                    self.overDueData.append(iOveList)
                })

                self.tblOvedue.reloadData()
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
}
```

It may helps you thank you.

Comment: It's too early to clear the `dataSource`. Better move it inside `success case` just when it's going to be filled with new data.

Comment: Please accept my answer with click the tick mark. so that other can user get help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Clear here

```
case.success(let value):
let json  = JSON(value)
print(json)
let data = json["inspections_overdue_data"]
print(data)
if data == []{
    self.viewNodata.isHidden = false
}else{
    self.overDueData.removeAll()
    data.array?.forEach({ (iunOverDue) in
        let iOveList = OvedueModel(surveyor_id: iunOverDue["surveyor_id"].stringValue, country: iunOverDue["country"].stringValue, time: iunOverDue["time"].stringValue, address2: iunOverDue["address2"].stringValue, address3: iunOverDue["address3"].stringValue, notes: iunOverDue["notes"].stringValue, house_num: iunOverDue["house_num"].stringValue, name: iunOverDue["name"].stringValue, address1: iunOverDue["address1"].stringValue, latitude: iunOverDue["latitude"].stringValue, eircode: iunOverDue["eircode"].stringValue, date_inspected: iunOverDue["date_inspected"].stringValue, property_id: iunOverDue["property_id"].stringValue, county: iunOverDue["county"].stringValue, client_id: iunOverDue["client_id"].stringValue, longitude: iunOverDue["longitude"].stringValue)
        self.searchResult = self.overDueData
        self.overDueData.append(iOveList)
    })

    self.tblOvedue.reloadData()
}
```

You can also declare the array as Set to remove similar objects

Comment: inside the button or callback

Answer (score 0):

It's simple...just because on refresh you are calling 'OverdueList' but failed to clear data from an array of overDueData. That's the reason you are getting data repeated.

For this, you just need to do this as simple.

```
@IBAction func btnRefreshTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {    
     self.overDueData.removeAll()
     self.OverdueList()    
}
```